# Set ACL on file_put_contents using PHP AWS SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-s3

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'MY_KEY',
    'secret' => 'MY_SECRET'
));

// Register the stream wrapper from a client object
$client->registerStreamWrapper();

$data = $_POST["image_data"];

list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);

file_put_contents('s3://webcamapp/filename.png', $data);
```

This code works fine and dandy and I'm seeing my images upload to my bucket. But I need to set the ACL to public-read as I'm sending this file to S3 because I will be displaying the images on my website. I can't figure out a way to do it using this method. Ideas?

Answer (score 13):

The S3 Stream Wrapper supports additional parameters to S3 via stream contexts. Try something like this:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    's3' => array(
        'ACL' => 'public-read'
    )
));

file_put_contents('s3://webcamapp/filename.png', $data, 0, $context);
```